# How to open a window from an external site in an application - fluttter

Tags: flutter, deep-linking

I am new to the filter programming language. I want to make an external login page that is not in the application. It comes from an external site or application as a unified access. After entering, I return to the application, keeping the login data and name in the application. How to save the data without the need to log in every time. Please help with full thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdJrS.png)